# No node publishing postion data

Tags: ros, optitrack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I have a small query about the vrpn_client_ros package on ROS indigo.

I have an Optitirack system with tracking tools installed and the VRPN server enabled. When I try to launch the node with:

$ `roslaunch vrpn_client_ros sample.launch server:=<Comp with tracking tools ip>`

However, when I launch it I do not see any nodes when I use rostopic list. Do you know how to resolve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216572/no-node-publishing-postion-data/) by [KBrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/23689/kbrown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-08-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [neu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30281/neu/) on 2017-05-08**:
I install vrpn_client_ros, I can run the launch file (roslaunch vrpn_client_ros sample.launch server: = "239.255.42.99"), the terminal tells me: "connection established", my problem is when in a new terminal I am running rostopic list does not appear the published topics.

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-28**:
@KBrown did u able to solve it? I have faced similar problem.Can you help me in solving the error? This is the steps I followed to connect Motive with Ros 1. I git clone the file from https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/... 2. exported it using the export command export VRPN_ROOT=path to where VRP

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-28**:
4.Run catkin_make 5. Launch using $roslaunch vrpn_client_ros sample.launch server:=239.255.42.99 when i ran it, it says the connection is established but when i tried to run $rostopic command it says that the topic didnt established yet. What did I get wrong? I really need your help.

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-28**:
Can you guide me through on how to create a connection between motive and ROS? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To see running nodes, use `rosnode list` instead. If there are no topics/messages published (since none show up with `rostopic list`, try to debug your VRPN connection. Try using the `vrpn_print_devices` command to receive messages from your VRPN Tracker over CLI. When this works, specify the Tracker name manually to the node in the `trackers` [parameter](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/vrpn_client_ros/blob/indigo-devel/launch/sample.launch#L19). When this works, try automatic tracker detection.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KBrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/23689/kbrown/) on 2015-10-01**:
I debugged the connection. When IT were in solving other unrelated issues I got them to change the firewall setting on the computer running tracking tools. Enabling port 3883. Now it runs great.

**Comment by [msanghv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/27341/msanghv2/) on 2016-07-13**:
I am having the same issue. Can you shed some more ligh on what I should do after I print vrpn_print_devices? I have already enabled port 3883 in my firewall

**Comment by [mario1577](https://answers.ros.org/users/30158/mario1577/) on 2017-04-26**:
how can I run the vrpn_print_devices??

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2017-04-26**:
Install ros--vrpn

**Comment by [mario1577](https://answers.ros.org/users/30158/mario1577/) on 2017-04-26**:
Thanks for replying, I install vrpn_client_ros, I can run the launch file (roslaunch vrpn_client_ros sample.launch server: = "239.255.42.99"), the terminal tells me: "connection established", my problem is when in a new terminal I am running rostopic list does not appear the published topics.

**Comment by [mario1577](https://answers.ros.org/users/30158/mario1577/) on 2017-04-26**:
What is the problem I have ?,Do  I have to do a network configuration in my pc ubuntu ? (I am noob in ubuntu).
I have the two PCs connected with an ethernet cable

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-27**:
I have run
$ roslaunch vrpn_client_ros sample.launch server:=
and it says that the connection is established but I didnt get any data from the motive.

**Comment by [UbuntuROs](https://answers.ros.org/users/30914/ubunturos/) on 2017-06-27**:
Is there any other code I should run? I tried to run
$ rostopic echo TrackerID/pose
on another terminal. When I use the comman rostopic list
I got /rosout and /rosout_agg